# Cannot add list of objects to my collection

Tags: java, android, listview, collections, android-recyclerview

In my main activity I have two lists:

```
private List<Feed> feedItems;

private ArrayList<Object> adItems() {
    ArrayList<Object> adItems = new ArrayList<>();
    adItems.add("image");
    adItems.add("image");
    adItems.add("image");
    return adItems;
}
```

The first list represents my feedItems, which are taken from my network model. The second list is simply a list of static images. I'm trying to set up native advertisements but I'm taking it a step back and simply supplying my feed with images to prove that overriding my RecyclerAdapter to produce multiple views works.

```
feedRecyclerAdapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(this, feedItems, new ImageLoader(new FeedItemFileCache(this)), adItems());
```

Here I pass my adItems() list of objects in the my FeedRecyclerAdapter as the last paramater, and in the adapter class itself I call it in the constructor:

```
public FeedRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feedItems, ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader, List<Object> adItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    this.feedItemImageLoader = feedItemImageLoader;
    feedItems.addAll(adItems);
}
```

This last line `feedItems.addAll(adItems);` is where I get the following error message:

```
Error:(43, 18) error: no suitable method found for addAll(List<Object>)
method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends Feed>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; List<Object> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Feed>)
method List.addAll(Collection<? extends Feed>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; List<Object> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Feed>)
```

My Feed object looks like this:

```
public class Feed {
    public static final String CLASS_NAME = "Feed";
    public static final String MARKET_CLASS_NAME = "MarketFeed";

    private String objectId;
    private String createdAt;
    /**
     * Can be a ParsePointer but we are using a relational include query to get the whole object
     */
    private Design designId;

    // Not part of the model, calculated at run time.
    private String timestampText;
    private boolean isInPersonalGallery;
    private boolean isLiked;
    private List<Comment> comments;

    // Related to Market Feed Items
    private DisplayedSide displayedSide = DisplayedSide.FRONT;

    public enum DisplayedSide {
        FRONT,
        BACK
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public Design getDesign() {
        return designId;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(createdAt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Feed", "Couldn't parse createdAt date when requested " + createdAt);
        }

        return date;
    }

    public String getTimestampText() {
        return timestampText;
    }

    public void setTimestampText(String timestampText) {
        this.timestampText = timestampText;
    }

    public boolean isInPersonalGallery() {
        return isInPersonalGallery;
    }

    public void setInPersonalGallery(boolean inPersonalGallery) {
        isInPersonalGallery = inPersonalGallery;
    }

    public boolean isLiked() {
        return isLiked;
    }

    public void setLiked(boolean liked) {
        isLiked = liked;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public DisplayedSide getDisplayedSide() {
        return displayedSide;
    }

    public void setDisplayedSide(DisplayedSide displayedSide) {
        this.displayedSide = displayedSide;
    }
}
```

In summary, I'm trying to sprinkle some images, or adItems, between the main objects in my Collection, feedItems. Why can't I simply attach them to my main list? And what can I do instead?

Comment: A `List<Feed>` is only supposed to hold `Feed` objects. If you want it to hold anything, it has to be `List<Object>`.

Comment: @bluemunch your type isnt matching

Comment: your error itself describing the problem : **argument mismatch; List<Object> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Feed>**

Comment: My problem is that if I make adItems a Feed object list they will have all the attributes of a Feed object, which I do not want. What is the alternative? Ad objects and Feed objects need to be in the same list.

Comment: Just use `List<Object>`, and you can put whatever you want into it.

Comment: @bluemunch take arrayList of object in to Feed model class.

Comment: I can't change List<Feed> to List<Object> if that's what you're suggesting. There should be another way around this.

Comment: Well, you can't keep anything that is not a `Feed` in a `List<Feed>`. Period. No way around it, because that's what `List<Feed>` is for.

Comment: Right, so the solution would be to create a new list and put each of the different types of objects into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onCreate method of my main activity I set adItems to be a Feed list, then passed it to my RecyclerAdapter constructor:

```
List<Feed> adItems = new ArrayList<>();
feedRecyclerAdapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(this, feedItems, new ImageLoader(new FeedItemFileCache(this)), adItems);
```

In my RecyclerAdapter class I added all adItems to the feedItems list so that I could operate over a single list:

```
public FeedRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feedItems, ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader, List<Feed> adItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    this.feedItemImageLoader = feedItemImageLoader;
    feedItems.addAll(adItems);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are set in wrong array

```
 feedItems.addAll(adItems);//you are set adItems in wrong arraylist (feedItems is a feetItem array list not a adItem list)

public FeedRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feedItems, ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader, List<Object> adItems) {
this.context = context;
this.feedItems = feedItems;
this.feedItemImageLoader = feedItemImageLoader;
feedItems.addAll(adItems);
}`
```

Comment: I want to ad "addItems" to the feedItems list. That is my intention.